# Can't find the installer_rversion-windows.exe to start the Android SDK Tools Setup wizard

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3, android-sdk-manager

I have downloaded the standalone SDK (sdk-tools-windows-3859397.zip) from the below link:
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#Other

But, it doesnt have the "installer_rversion-windows.exe" to start the Android SDK Tools Setup wizard.

[image: contents from the sdk-tools-windows-3859397.zip]

Not sure how should I go ahead and install the standalone Android SDK. I am using eclipse Mars as of now.

-Regards,
Aaron

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same problem,instead of using Android SDK Tools Setup wizard,my solution is use command-line to install/uninstall the package that I need.

For example,if I want to install the "Android SDK Platform-tools":

1)Lunch **CMD** shell

2)Change the current directory to your SDK directory

3)type **sdkmanager platform-tools**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [sdkmanager commands](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html#usage) for installing components through command line